# VSTS (TFS): Is there a way to generate TRX files as part of a run using Release Management?

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We're using release manager in VSTS online to automatically stand up machines and kick off tests on them.  The problem is, the test agents don't appear to generate TRX files (test result files) on the machines on which the tests run.  We need these files so we can do some custom reporting.

Is there a way to set up the Run Functional Tests environment in such a way as to generate those TRX files and maybe store them somewhere?  The options in Release Management doesn't seem to support this.

My alternative is to use the VSTS REST API to download it all, but so far as I can tell that means getting a huge list of available test runs for a project, digging through it to find the run I want, and *then* being able to get the list of results and download them.

Basically, that means my two options are (keeping in mind that we might have multiple results files spread across multiple test machines in a single release):

*Finding Generated TRX Files:*

1. Copy the TRX files to a single location
2. Play with the TRX files

*Using the REST API*

1. Call the API to get a list of runs.
2. Find each run in my automation run (it seems to be one run per machine, so an automation run that runs over 10 machines generates 10 runs).
3. For each run, get the list of results files that are available.
4. For each results file, download it

The first method would be vastly easier, if I could get the test agent to actually write the TRX file to disk.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Do you try to specify testsetting or runsetting?

Comment: We use a testsettings file, which doesn't seem to support results manipulation.

Comment: Actually, I have a theory: Release manager doesn't generate a TRX file at all.  Instead it publishes the results to TFS.  /logger:Publish instead of /logger:trx.

Answer (score 0):

I submit a user voice here: [Generate and remain test result file (trx) for Run functional test step/task](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18572935-generate-and-remain-test-result-file-trx-for-run).

The other workaround is that you can run test again through PowerShell with VSTest.Console.exe or MSTest.exe command by using [PowerShell On Target Machine](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines).